# How can I show comments for specific posts?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to show comments for every specific service in my website..
the store comment method is working properly!
and when I try to display comments in the blade page I get this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comments.service_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `comments` where `comments`.`service_id` = 11 and `comments`.`service_id` is not null) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\dawerelzirou\resources\views\service\showservice.blade.php)

CommentsController.php (store comment)

```
public function store(Request $request,  $services_id)
{
   $this->validate($request,array(
        'body'=>'required',
    ));


  $comment=new Comment;

  $comment->body=$request->body;
  $comment->user_id=$request->user()->id;
  $comment->services_id=$services_id;
  $comment->save();



  $request->session()->flash('notif','success');
  return back();
}
```

this is Comment.php

```
         class Comment extends Model{ 


            public function  user() {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\User');}



             public function  services() {
             return $this->belongsTo('App\Service');}

                         }
```

This is Service.php

```
     class Service extends Model{




public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\comment');

}
       }
```

The blade page :

```
@if (count($services->comments)>0)

       @foreach ($services->comments as $comment)
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col s6 offset-l3">
            <div class="card small" style="height:auto;width:700px;">
            <div class="card-content center-align">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
        <img src="/img/bg.jpeg" class="responsive-img circle center-align" 
        style="width:50%;" alt="">
        </div>
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col s12">
     <p>$comment->user->username </p>
       </div>
       </div>
        <br>
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col s12">
       <p>$comment->body</p>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
          </div>

          </div>
          </div>
          </div> 
       @endforeach
          @endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always add proper local and foreign keys while making the relations in laravel if you are not using naming conventions because laravel uses snakecase naming convrntions

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has specific naming conventions - your column should be `service_id`, not `services_id`. Since you're *not* using that naming convention, you need to tell the relationship what column to look in:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\comment', 'services_id');
```

Note also that on some operating systems with case-sensitive file names, `App\Comment` and `App\comment` are different things. Make sure you're using the right capitalization - either `App\Comment`, `class Comment`, and `Comment.php`, **or** `App\comment`, `class comment`, and `comment.php`. Not a mix!

Comment: yes sorry I just typed by mistake the wrong capitalization , I edited it...
but I don't think the problem is from " $services_id" instead of " $service_id"..

Comment: @AtefRihane Try it and see. It's very clear to me that this is your problem. See how you're doing `$comment->services_id` but Laravel's making queries that reference `service_id`?

Comment: I just modified as you told me but I still get the same error. :s

Comment: The **exact** same error? As in it's still complaining about the singular `service_id` column? Or just similar?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comments.$services_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `comments` where `comments`.`$services_id` = 11 and `comments`.`$services_id` is not null)

Comment: Not `'$services_id'`. `'services_id'`. **Don't add a `$` to what I posted.**